# REGEX search & replace with sed or other command

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed, sql

I have a big SQL file with content like

```
[code language="bash"]
git checkout master
git pull origin master
...
[/code]
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elitUt enim ad minim 
[code]some other code[/code]
veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
[code language="php"]var_dump($data);[/code]
```

And I want to replace the `[code language="{lang}"]{wrapped-code}[/code]` by `<pre><code class="language-{lang}">{wrapped-code}</code></pre>`

So the final output will look like

```
<pre><code class="language-bash">
git checkout master
git pull origin master
...
</code></pre>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elitUt enim ad minim 
<pre><code>some other code</code></pre>
veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
<pre><code class="language-php">var_dump($data);</code></pre>
```

Please let me know how we can achieve this with sed or other find and replace command.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -e 's/\[code language="\([^"]*\)"\]/<pre><code class="language-\1">/' \
    -e 's!\[/code\]!</code></pre>!' \
    < input  > output
```

The square brackets have to be escaped so that they don't represent a set of characters; I then capture the text between the quotes to use in the replacement (as `\1`); for the second search & replacement, I used `!` as the separator to avoid [Leaning Toothpick Syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome) with the HTML end-tag replacements.

Comment: That works brilliantly. I forgot to mention that I have simple block as well `[code]some other code[/code]`  which needs to be converted as `<pre><code>some other code</code></pre>`

Comment: And why `-e` is used instead of `-E`?

Comment: Glad to hear it works for you; if you edit your question to include the `[code]` transformation, I'll update the Answer to cover that case as well.  I used `-e` because I think it's clearer than using semicolons to separate multiple statements. The `-E` flag is different; it turns on extended regular expressions.

Comment: waiting for your updated answer.

Comment: The question doesn’t yet talk about the transformation in your comment above; would you please add it? Thank you.